# Word for superficial (but unmerited) appearance of substance/character

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

What is a word for someone or something that superficially seems to have a lot of substance/character but is actually shallow/empty? I can't help but think I've heard a word like this before. "Glib" comes close but seems to speak more to words rather than character.

Comment: "Empty suit" is used in some contexts.

Comment: braggadocio or maybe braggart

Answer (score 1):

A colorful phrase for such a person, in U.S. English, is [**"all hat and no cattle."**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_hat_and_no_cattle) The literal reference is someone who dresses and maybe acts like a cowboy (with a fancy [ten-gallon hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboy_hat), for example), but knows nothing about ranching, and is used more generally to describe someone who is all show and no substance.

If you're looking for a single word, here are a couple of options:

- [**pretentious**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pretentious). Claiming that or behaving as if one is important or deserving of merit when such is not the case.
- [**poseur**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/poseur) (or **poser**). One who affects a particular attribute, attitude, or identity to impress or influence others.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [phony](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/phony) in the sense of: *5. an insincere or affected person.*

You might also use a number of the synonyms listed under *2. One who fakes:* in the thesaurus section of the same definition.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a proverb rather than a word will do.

**empty vessels make most noise (or sound)**

> Those with least wisdom or knowledge are always the most talkative. —  [ODD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/empty-vessels-make-most-noise-or-sound)

Essentially this proverb is the antoymn of *Still waters run deep*.